# How can I fix "IndexError: only integers" in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

(Solved. See answer below) I am teaching myself Python in preparation for a school project. I ran into the following error that I cannot figure out how to fix:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Here is the code I am trying to run (edited it some based on comments)

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import i
from mpmath import *
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

N = 3
M = np.zeros(shape=(N, N))
for n in range(0, N):
    M[0, n] = fac(n)    # mpmath.fac
for m in range(1, N):
    for n in range(0, N):
        M[m, n] = (Sum(M[m - 1, i], (i, 0, n + 1))) / (n+1) 
print(M)
```

Essentially, I want to specify a dimension for the array and a first row for the array. Then I want construct the remaining entries in the array in a certain way (Holder summability if you know about that summation technique).

I have looked over various other questions in stack overflow with this particular error but the questions were beyond my current knowledge or did not exactly address my issue. I have fiddled with many of the parameters and have isolated the issue to line 13. In particular, as soon as I put "i" inside M[m-1,i], I receive the error. My code runs if I put any number less than the dimension instead of "i" but this is not the construction I need.

For example, the entry `M[2,1]` should be constructed as:

`M[2,1] = (M[1,0] + M[1,1]) / 2`

Which I thought corresponded to the sum I had written. How did my indexes become something other than a positive integer?

Thanks!

Comment: The "i" in `M[m - 1, i]` is suspect: it does not appear correctly defined/assigned elsewhere

Comment: On Sympy.org where I was following along I saw the example: >>> from sympy.abc import k, a, b
>>> from sympy import Sum
>>> Sum(1/k, (k, 2, 5)).doit().evalf()       Here, they refer to k in the sum. I though it was standard practice to utilize your index in a sum. Sorry for the formatting. I don't know how to press "enter" to generate space in a comment.

Comment: Stop star-importing everything. You wouldn't have had this problem if you hadn't star-imported everything out of `sympy.abc`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I saw that syntax in a getting started guide so I used it. I switched to "import numpy as np" and "from sympy.abc import i." Unfortunately, the error persists.

Comment: ...wait, you imported `i` deliberately? Okay, looking closer, you seem to be using `i` as a summation symbol for a sympy `Sum`, so that was probably deliberate. Mixing sympy and numpy like that doesn't work; they don't understand each other, and `M` doesn't know how to build an expression object for `M[m - 1, i]`.

Comment: (You should still avoid star imports, though. It is way too easy to accidentally use the wrong function because you pulled something you weren't expecting in a star import.)

Comment: I have removed all instances of star imports. Thank you. Even with this, and hpaulj answer below about switching to sympy arrays, I was not able to receive the desired matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `numpy` and `sympy`, and it's giving problems:

Your `sympy` import defines `i` as a symbol (that's not obvious to `numpy` users):

```
In [1]: from sympy.abc import *
In [2]: i
Out[2]: i
```

then you define a `numpy` array.  (`import numpy as np` is better than `*`):

```
In [3]: M=np.zeros((3,3))
```

trying to use this `i` as index raises your error:

```
In [4]: M[1,i]
------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

A symbol may work in a `sympy` matrix, but it does not work when indexing a numpy array.

```
Ms = sy.zeros(3,3)      # sympy matrix  
for m in range(1,3):
    for n in range(3):
        Ms[m,n] = (sy.Sum(Ms[m-1,i],(i,0,n+1)))/(n+1)
```

This runs, though the resulting `Ms` doesn't make much sense.

So the root of the problem is that you are mixing numpy and sympy, possibly through ignorance, and possibly because of the `*` imports.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I switched to "import numpy as np" and "from sympy.abc import i" rather than star importing. Unfortunately, I still have the error. How do i receive an honest working index in this case?

Comment: Use a sympy matrix rather than a numpy array.

Comment: I see. I was able to get it to run but with some odd print in the log. Strange and sporadic spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error based on everyone's help here. Thanks! I see that I should not star-import everything and that I should stick with either sympy or numpy so they aren't fighting each other. I was successfully able to rewrite my program to correctly build the Holder sums. Here is my running code:

```
import sympy as sy
import mpmath as mp
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
sy.init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)
N = 5
M = np.zeros((N, N))
for n in range(0, N):                       
    M[0, n] = mp.fac(n)
for n in range(0, N):                      
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        M[1, n] += (M[0, i])
for m in range(2, N):                       
    for n in range(0, N):
        for i in range(0, n + 1):
            M[m, n] += (M[m - 1, i])
        M[m, n] = M[m, n] / (n + 1)
print(M)
```

This correctly (and beautifully) prints:

```
[[ 1.          1.          2.          6.         24.        ]
 [ 1.          2.          4.         10.         34.        ]
 [ 1.          1.5         2.33333333  4.25       10.2       ]
 [ 1.          1.25        1.61111111  2.27083333  3.85666667]
 [ 1.          1.125       1.28703704  1.53298611  1.99772222]]
```

Thanks again for the help!